# jQuery form reset button for all entered values

Tags: jquery, html

I am using a form and a reset button where I can reset all the entered values but it is not working at all.

When I debugged with the Firefox console tab, I saw an error `illegal character` at the end of the jQuery script. Can someone tell me what is the wrong part here?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-IN">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery1.7.2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('#reset').click(function(){
        $(':input','#myform')
        .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
        .val('')
        .removeAttr('checked')
        .removeAttr('selected');
    });​
</script>
<form id='myform'>
  <input type='text' value='test' />
    <select>
      <option>One</option>
      <option selected="true">Two</option>
    </select>
    <select multiple="true" size="5">
      <option>One</option>
      <option selected="true">Two</option>
    </select>
    <input type='button' id='reset' value='reset' />
</form>​
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: working fine here http://jsfiddle.net/MAwTg/

Comment: but its not working here with plain html and jQuery.

Comment: have you run the above fiddle

Comment: Did you try `$('#reset').on('everything', function(){ format c: });`

Comment: @rahul..The fiddle code is exactly same I think.Then why its not working here?

Comment: @newuser: Updated my answer - jQuery solution works fine now, please check!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('#reset').click(function() {
        $(':input','#myform')
            .not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden')
            .val('')
            .removeAttr('checked')
            .removeAttr('selected');
    });
});
```

You're running the javascript before the DOM is ready. `$(function() {})` only runs when the DOM is ready. Read more here: [`.ready()`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: @newuser Just pasted your code into my IDE. There is some kind of invisible char in the end of your `});`. If you just remove that or paste the code I've written it should work.

Comment: @sQVe... nope..The same problem going here.I have made paste your total code but its not working.

Comment: @newuser Works find for me, get full code from here : http://pastebin.com/5zvwR5KH

Comment: After 5 years your answer helps me. Thankyou.

Answer (score 14):

Won't the `<input type="reset" >` suffice?

```
<form>

   <input type='reset'  />

</form>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mrobin/MAwTg/1/)**

Answer (score 9):

#### The other jQuery solution for resetting the form fields would be:

```
$('#form')[0].reset(); or $('#form').get(0).reset();
```

#### Another one, more specific, referring to the required fields:

```
$('#form').find('input, select').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
```

[jsFiddle Working Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7NKzt/) - jQuery Solution

#### Using only JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('form').reset();
```

#### Using only HTML:

As it was mentioned in one of the answers, in most cases you don't need JavaScript for resetting the form fields, it works just by settings `type="reset"` to the button, e.g.:

```
<button type="reset" value="Reset">Reset</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The JQuery below will reset all text and dropdowns;

Just replace the **#YourID** with the ID of the field/input you're looking to reset, for multiple inputs, duplicate the lines and add ID's where appropriate

```
$(".btn-reset").click(function () { 
    $(this).closest('form').find("input[type=text], textarea").val(""); 
    $('#YourID').removeAttr('selected').find('option:eq(0)').prop('selected', true); 
});
```